# Find command to count how many files are in a directory containing a certain string without counting sub directories

Tags: linux, files, find

I am writing the below command:

```
find . -mtime -1 -type f -exec grep -ln '20191122' {} \; | wc -l
```

which is allowing me to find all files modified within one day, that contain a string of "20191122", and finally then outputting how many files fit the description.

However, there is also sub-directories in the directory I am in, which also have been updated within one day, and they too are counted in the `wc -l`.

I thought using `-type f` would just count the 'files' not directories.

Can anyone see the mistake or help?

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `find ... -type f` will only find files, but it will do so recursively down *into* subdirectories.

To only apply the `grep` to files in the current directory, also use `-maxdepth 1` with your GNU `find` command.  This will stop `find` from descending down more than one level (i.e. into the current directory only).

If you at some point want to do the same on a Unix whose `find` utility does not implement `-maxdepth`, you may consider

```
find . ! -name . -prune -mtime -1 -type f -exec grep -ln '20191122' {} \;
```

This avoids descending into any other directory than `.` by using `-prune`.

As for counting the files, it would be safer to use `grep` only to detect the pattern in a file and then output something that `wc -l` would count correctly.  If you have filenames containing embedded newlines in their names, `wc -l` will miscount.

For example:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -mtime -1 -type f -exec grep -q '20191122' {} \; -exec echo x \; | wc -l
```

This would output a single line with the character `x` for each file that contains the string, and `wc -l` would then count these lines.

Comment: Since the primary `-maxdepth` is not one of the useless GNU enhancements, this is supported by most modern `find` implementations, like BSD find and `sfind`. But thank you for mentioning that this is not one of the so called standard features.

Comment: @schily Is there something missing from the answer? The user is on Linux, so I'm assuming that they have GNU `find`.

Comment: No, there is nothing missing, but answering with nonstandard enhancements is expected to cause problems for people on platforms that do not implement this specific extension and this is a forum for UNIX.

Comment: @schily Sorted, I believe.

Comment: Yes i used the -maxdepth and it worked fine. Thank you